# Getting the checked checkboxes in an html table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-selectors

I have made a table as below.

in script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#addSelected").live("click", function(e) {
              alert("Entered");
              $('#LstDocTemp tr').each(function() {
                  alert($('.chk').is('checked'));
                  if ($('.chk').is('checked')) {
                      alert("Clicked");
                  }
              });
         });
    });
</script>
```

the html part:

```
<div class="grid_top_button">
    <div class="left_top_curve">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="right_top_curve">
      &nbsp;
    </div><input type="button" id="addSelected" name="addSelected" class="section_btn"
    value="Link" />
  </div>

  <table id="LstDocTemp" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=
  "instruction_grid">
    <tr>
      <th align="left" class="ins_sl_no">Sl No.</th>

      <th align="left" class="selct_column"><input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll"
      name="chkSelectAll" /></th>

      <th align="left" class="doc_title_1">Document title</th>

      <th align="left" class="description">Description</th>

      <th align="center" class="revision">Revision</th>

      <th align="left" class="part_no">Parts name</th>

      <th align="center" class="issue_no">Issue</th>

      <th align="center">Link</th>
    </tr><% int slNo = 1; %><%foreach (var item in Model)
                              { %>

    <tr id="<%= Html.Encode(item.DocId) %>">
      <td><%= slNo %></td>

      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" class="chk" id=
      "chkbox_&lt;%=Html.Encode(item.DocId) %&gt;" /></td>

      <td><%= Html.Hidden("DocTitle", item.DocTitle)%> <a href=
      '%3C%=%20Url.Action("DetailsDocumentTemplate",%20"Document",%20new%20{%20id%20=%20item.DocId%20})%%3E'>
      <%=Html.Encode(item.DocTitle) %></a></td>

      <td><%= Html.Hidden("DocDesc", item.DocDesc)%><%= Html.Encode(item.DocDesc) %></td>

      <td class="dark_highlight">
      <%= Html.Hidden("DocRevision", item.DocRevision)%><%= Html.Encode(item.DocRevision) %></td>

      <td>
      <%= Html.Hidden("PartListId", item.PartListId)%><%= Html.Hidden("PartNo", item.PartNo)%><%= Html.Encode(item.PartNo) %></td>

      <td class="light_highlight">
      <%= Html.Hidden("IssueNo", item.IssueNo)%><%=Html.Encode(item.IssueNo) %></td>

      <td><%= Html.Hidden("DocId", item.DocId)%><a class="icon_add" title=
      "Add">Add</a></td>
    </tr><%slNo++;
                              } %>
  </table>
```

`alert($('.chk').is('checked'));` in the script is always returning false. I need to do an updation action for all the rows that are selected by checking the corresponding checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I believe $('.chk') will return all checkboxes in the grid.

You want to do somehting like this (untested!) :

```
$('#LstDocTemp tr').each(function() {           
    alert($(this).children('.chk').is('checked'));                   
if ($(this).children('.chk').is('checked')) {                       
alert("Clicked");                   
}
```

})

Comment: This seems to always return false.. I need the exact same thing as the OP needs.